# Keras predicting scalar value from a vector via NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vector, binary

I want to predict the scalar value (between 0 and 100) from the given vector (size=250, binary elements). I have a dataset, which contains 1000 x values and 1000 y values:

```
>>>in_.shape
(1000, 250)

>>>in_[0]
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...])

>>>out.shape
(1000,)

>>>out[0]
64.46677867594474
```

I wrote a model, but it seems like not working. Here is the code piece, and here you may find the dataset https://ufile.io/f/yt61u:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


in_ = np.load('input.npy')
out = np.load('output.npy')

model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.Input(shape=(250,)),
        layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(in_, out, batch_size=100, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)
```

**How can I improve this?**

```
Epoch 1/5
9/9 [==============================] - 2s 54ms/step - loss: -240.3843 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -54.9291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
9/9 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: -311.0255 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -54.9291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
9/9 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: -311.0255 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -54.9291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
9/9 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: -311.0254 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -54.9291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
9/9 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: -311.0255 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: -54.9291 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: You are using a loss for binary classification. Try out Mean squared error for regression tasks such as yours. Additionally, I would look into pre-processing yor data to make it more amendable for use with neural networks, such as normalisation and quantisation.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape=(250,)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(44, activation='relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse',
              metrics=tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsolutePercentageError())

model.fit(in_, out, batch_size=1, epochs=25)
```

Comment: last layer activation is set relu!

Comment: @Innat is this a bad thing? could you explain? I tried with sigmoid, but it was performing worse than relu...?